# Default View contract in Splat

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I am using ReactiveUI in a modular WPF app: main app dynamically loads DLLs with ViewModels and Views.

I use `resolver.RegisterViewsForViewModels(newAssembly);` to automatically register all views from assembly.

Now, I want to add read-only views for some view models. I came up with the idea to use contracts and ViewModelViewHost.Contract - it should do the work.

Is there a way to mark a view with a contract so that `RegisterViewsForViewModels` would register it with it?

If not, will it be enough to register the read-only view with contract? Will `RegisterViewsForViewModels` break if I have more than one view per VM?

Answer (score 1):

The source code for RegisterViewsForViewModels() is located https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/50403240c792d6d870fbe74961d5df297b4a1f2e/src/ReactiveUI/IDependencyResolver.cs

I imagine you could modify the method to look for your IReadOnlyViewFor or something and register with the contract name.

Comment: yes, I've the source code and there is an attribute implemented that does exactly that. I just tested it and it works